# How to add user avatar to notifications?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter app that receives notifications from firebase cloud messaging (FCM) and wonder how I can add user's avatar to the notification similar to what the Instagram app shows right now.

I tried adding "image" to the payload but that will be expandable image which is not what I want. Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `Data message` not `Notification Message`. you can read about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

so we have a payload like this :

```
{
"to": "TOPIC or TOKEN",
"data": {
    "title": "Hi User",
    "message": "Welcome to notifications",
    "avatar":"https://picsum.photos/30/30",
    "user_id":"vhdrjb"
}}
```

Solution for **Android** :

Implement methods for `foreground, background (terminated)` :

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackgroundMessage);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) async {
  onForegroundMessage(event);
});
```

and when you want to show notification use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

at first you should download the image :

```
  Future<String> _downloadAndSaveFile(String url, String fileName) async {
final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName.png';
final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
final File file = File(filePath);
await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
return filePath;
```

}

and you can show notification like this:

```
  Future<void> show(String title, String message, String avatar, String userId,
  int messageId) async {
final String url = await _downloadAndSaveFile(avatar, userId);
final AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'vhdrjb_fcm_notification_channel',
    'vhdrjb_fcm_notification',
    channelDescription: 'media channel description',
    largeIcon: FilePathAndroidBitmap(url),
    styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(
      message,
      contentTitle: title,
      summaryText: message.substring(0, message.length ~/ 2),
    )
);
final NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin?.show(messageId, title, message, notificationDetails);
```

}

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score -3):

There are two types of Notification Style which may suit your requirements:

1. [NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#large-style)
   [image: NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle]
2. [NotificationCompat.InboxStyle](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#inbox-style)
   [image: NotificationCompat.InboxStyle]

Given the link too how the payload needs to be structured.

Comment: I don't see any options in FCM to set the notification style and pass the icon without it expanding.

There's also documentations on creating Conversation notification on Android 11 but there's no straightforward way of creating long-lived sharing shortcuts in flutter..
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/conversations